# Return render_template y un json Flask Python

Tags: html, python, json, flask, google-chart-api

Tengo un problema a la hora de cargar mis datos en la gráfica de google charts, resulta que si quiero regresar mi valor, en este caso llamado dato_json solo si se me genera la gráfica pero a la hora de hacerlo con render_template simplemente no hace nada, no me devuelve errores, ni tampoco alguna otra cosa, simplemente el espacio donde se genera la gráfica se queda en blanco

```
@app.route("/estadisticas", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def estadisticas(dato_json):

        dato_json = '{"cols": [{"id":"","label":"Egresados","pattern":"","type":"string"},'

        dato_json= dato_json + '{"id":"","label":"valor","pattern":"","type":"number"}],"rows": [' 

        #Realizacion de la consulta para obtener los datos 
        db = get_db()
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute("select distinct cargoactual from mse.egresados")
        result = cursor.fetchall()

        #Contador de Registros
        contRow = 0

        #Ciclo para cada dato obtenido
        while contRow < len (result):

            #Obtiene el Registro
            registro = result[contRow]
            print("Registro:",registro)

            #Obtiene la Columna
            columna = registro[0]
            print("Columna:",columna)

            #Prepara una nueva Consulta
            cursor.execute("select count(*) from mse.egresados where cargoactual = '"+ columna +"'" )
            result2 = cursor.fetchall()

            #Obtiene el valor
            valor = str(result2[0][0])
            print("Valor:",valor )

            #Obtener el año
            cursor.execute("select distinct extract(year from fechatomagrado) from mse.egresados where cargoactual = '"+ columna +"' order by extract(year from fechatomagrado)" )
            result3 = cursor.fetchall()

            #Obtiene el valor
            año = str(result3[0][0])

            #Agrega el row al dato_json con la columna y el valor
            dato_json = dato_json + '{"c":[{"v":"'+año+'","f":null},{"v":'+valor+',"f":null},{"v":'+valor+',"f":null}]}' 

            #Verifica si no es el ultimo renglon para agregar una coma
            if(contRow < len(result)-1):
                dato_json = dato_json + ","

        #Incrementa el Contador de Row
            contRow = contRow + 1

        #Coloca el cierre del dato_json
        dato_json = dato_json +  "]}"

        print("dato_json", dato_json)
        cursor.close()
        return render_template("estadisticas.html", dato_json=dato_json)
```

Aquí es donde se carga la gráfica, hago el llamado a la url /estadisticas

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    // Carga de la grafica
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var jsonData = $.ajax({
          url: "/estadisticas",
          dataType: "json",
          type: "GET",
          async: false
          }).responseText;
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

        var options = {
          chart: {
            title: 'Cantidad de Egresados por año',
            subtitle: "",
          },
          bars: 'vertical',
          vAxis: {format: 'decimal'},
          height: 400,
          colors: ['#1b9e77', '#d95f02', '#7570b3']
        };

        var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

        chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));

        var btns = document.getElementById('btn-group');

        btns.onclick = function (e) {

          if (e.target.tagName === 'BUTTON') {
            options.vAxis.format = e.target.id === 'none' ? '' : e.target.id;
            chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
          }
        }
      }

    </script>
```

Si hago solo el return del dato_json, si me logra generar la gráfica, pero con el render_template no, y necesito cargar ambos al mismo tiempo
Hay alguna forma de que me regrese ambos?

Comment: No necesitas tener el texto JSON en la función de Python, usa un diccionario común y silvestre. Ya que es una función AJAX lo que tienes que hacer es usar `jsonify` en vez de `render_tempate`.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba esto:

Debes pasar la variable flask a javascript
intenta

```
<javascript>
  var dataJson = {{ dato_json|tojson}}
</javascript>
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37259740/passing-variables-from-flask-to-javascript/37260465

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/templating/

Comment: como aplico eso? ya lo intente y me marca de error TypeError: Object of type Undefined is not JSON serializable